# How to configure Jackson2 XmlMapper to automatically detect repeated XML children nodes and replace them with a named array

Tags: xml-parsing, jackson2, jackson-dataformat-xml

I am using the following code:

```
            ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
            JsonNode jsonNode = xmlMapper.readTree("<fakeRoot>" + xmlText + "</fakeRoot>");
            String jsonString = jsonNode.toString();
            System.out.println("jsonString = " + jsonString);
```

I have the following value in the xmlText:

```
  <a>
      <b>
          <c>xxxx</c>
      </b>
      <b>
          <c>yyyy</c>
      </b>
      <b>
          <c>zzzz</c>
      </b>
  </a>
```

I would expect this JSON to be produced:

```
  {
    "a": {
      "b": [
        { "c": "xxxx" },
        { "c": "yyyy" },
        { "c": "zzzz" }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Why is the XmlMapper returning the following incorrect JSON?

```
{"a":{"b":{"c":"zzzz"}}}
```

How can I configure it to produce the desired JSON (without declaring any Java classes for each of the "a", "b", "c") ?

How can I configure XmlMapper to automatically detect repeated XML children nodes and replace them with a named array ?

Comment: To try to simplify the question, I removed this extra part:


The code should automatically work even if the input XML is, for example:
```
  <q>
    <w>
        <m>
            <c>xxxx</c>
        </m>
        <m>
            <c>yyyy</c>
        </m>
        <m>
            <c>zzzz</c>
        </m>
    </w>
    <t>
        <n>
            <p>1111</p>
        </n>
        <n>
            <p>2222</p>
        </n>
        <n>
            <p>1111</p>
        </n>
        <n>
            <p>2222</p>
        </n>
    </t>
  </q>
```

Comment: It should return the following JSON:
```
{
  "q": {
    "w": {
        "m": [
            { "c": "xxxx" },
            { "c": "yyyy" },
            { "c": "zzzz" },
        ]
    },
    "t": {
        "n": [
            { "p": "1111" },
            { "p": "2222" },
            { "p": "1111" },
            { "p": "2222" },
        ]
    }
  }
}
```